# Организация повторяющегося кода в шаблонах Flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask

Есть несколько html-блоков, которые повторяются во многих flask-шаблонах.

Например:

```
<!-- Footer -->
<div id="copyright" class="container">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="/link1">link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/link2">link2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Как избавиться от дублирования кода, чтобы править его в 1 месте, а не в каждом шаблоне по отдельности

Comment: Вынести в отдельный файл и делать include в нужных местах для вставки из этого файла

Comment: @andreymal Я понял о чем вы. Вы могли бы оставить ответ для других участников сообщества? Я готов его принять. Нет, так сам оформлю, спасибо)